# Accessing properties in an include when setting that include in to a file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a template html page which I will call via an include to set to a variable, this variable will then be used to set the value of a new file. I need the variables in the included file to be resolved so that the values are populated correctly.

To demo imagine these files:

**main.php**

```
$someVar = "someValue";
$fileText = include "aTemplate.php";
$newFileName = 'someFile.php';
if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $fileText) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
} else {
    echo "not created";
}
```

**aTemplate.php**

```
<?php 
return 
'<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $someVar; ?></title>
    </head>
</html>'
?>
```

What is currently happening is that the variables stay unresolved and hold no value so in the created html file the title is:

```
<title></title>
```

Instead of

```
<title>someValue</title>
```

How can I change the 'aTemplate.php' file to resolve the properties set in 'main.php'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this at your aTemplate.php:

```
<?php  
    return '<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>'. $someVar .'</title>
        </head>
    </html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should echo those string in page instead of return command.
The keyword return is used inside a function while your file is not a function. The browser simply puts what's inside include file has to offer. In you case it is HTML string which should be outputted using echo command.

Also the server executes code in top to bottom and left to right. Thus the variable $someVar will be accessed in aTemplate.php file.

Use below code instead to work

**main.php**

```
    $someVar = "someValue"; 

    $file = 'aTemplate.php';

    // Open the file to get existing content

$fileText = include "aTemplate.php";


     $newFileName = 'someFile.php'; 
    // Write the contents back to the new file

    if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $fileText) !== false) 
        { 
        echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")"; } 
        else { 
        echo "not created"; 
        }
```

**aTemplate.php**

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en"><head>
<title><?php echo $someVar;?></title>
 </head> 
</html>
```

Comment: Something is missing from the a.template example?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your template, firstly as you have the HTML in single quotes, this won't do any of the string substitutions.  Secondly, your trying to do a PHP echo whilst in HTML in PHP.  I've used [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to enclose the HTML as it allows any sorts of quotes and will also do the replacements.

The substitution of the value is just replaced by adding `$someVar` directly into the string.

So *aTemplate.php* becomes...

```
<?php
return <<< HTML
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>$someVar</title>
    </head>
</html>
HTML;
```